# Did Palpatine know about the Lost Tribe of Sith and Abeloth?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

It strikes me as weird that somebody so immersed with the Dark side, and so well learned wouldn't know about the Lost Tribe and Abeloth. He might have read about the other times Abeloth had emerged and the ships in the Sith armada that vanished, and he might have sensed the many dark side presences in the Outer Rim and whenever Abeloth was near the Maw.

Is their any shred of evidence to suggest he might have had a clue?

He knew about the Vong. Did he know about these other forces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my pretty extensive Googling, it appears that there is no evidence that Palpatine knew of either. (But there's no confirmation that he did NOT know).

Comment: Yeah In my heart of hearts, i know that be the answer.

Answer (score 7):

No the Lost Tribe crashed while transporting crystals in a dangerous area of space.  Their master would be killed in battle in the months following the crash and the supply convoy was assumed lost.  Until ship finds them post NJO no one knows that the tribe is out there.

Abeloth was trapped by the celestials in a prison created in the MAW.  Until centerpoint station was destroy in Legacy of the Force  she remained in prison there.  That set a chain of events in motion that freed her.  Only the Klikliks had any record of Abeloth from the last time she was fought.

So no neither were known to Palpatine.

Comment: Let's not forget that the ancient Sith knew a whole lot more about the dark side, but one of the Banite masters went mad and destroyed a lot of the knowledge. The Sith Order's knowledge base was severely setback by that event.